# how to overwrite part of a line in a txt file with regex and .sub in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, substring, substitution

I have the following layout in a txt file.

`[item] label1: comment1 | label2: foo`

I have the code below. The goal is to **modify part of an existing line in text**

```
def replace_info(item, bar)
return "please create a file first" unless File.exist?('site_info.txt')
    IO.foreach('site_info.txt','a+') do |line|
        if line.include?(item)
            #regex should find the data from the whitespace after the colon all the                     way to the end.
            #this should be equivalent to foo
            foo_string = line.scan(/[^"label2: "]*\z/)
            line.sub(foo_string, bar)
            end
        end
end
```

Please advise. Perhaps my `regrex` is off, but `.sub` is correct, but I cannot overwrite `line`.

Comment: `line.sub(foo_string, bar)` isn't saved. Perhaps you want something like `IO.foreach('site_info.txt','a+').map do |line|...`. I can't say for sure because you haven't stated what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Oh you want to modify an existing file. @Amadan explains how to do that. You still need to edit your question to explain--at the beginning--what you are trying to do.

Comment: @CarySwoveland clarified my intention, which is to modify a line of text in an existing file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tiny problem: Your regular expression does not do what you think. `/[^"label2: "]*\z/` means: any number of characters at the end of line that are not `a`, `b`, `e`, `l`, `"`, space, colon or `2` (see [Character classes](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes)). And `scan` returns an array, which `sub` doesn't work with. But that doesn't really matter, because...

Small problem: `line.sub(foo_string, bar)` doesn't do anything. It returns a changed string, but you don't assign it to anything and it gets thrown away. `line.sub!(foo_string, bar)` would change `line` itself, but that leads us to...

Big problem: You cannot just change the read line and expect it to change in the file itself. It's like reading a book, thinking you could write a line better, and expecting it to change the book. The way to change a line in a text file is to read from one file *and copy what you read to another*. If you change a line between reading and writing, the newly written copy will be different. At the end, you can rename the new file to the old file (which will delete the old file and replace it atomically with the new one).

EDIT: Here's some code. First, I dislike `IO.foreach` as I like to control the iteration myself (and IMO, `IO.foreach` is not readable as `IO#each_line`). In the regular expression, I used lookbehind to find the label without including it into the match, so I can replace just the value; I changed to `\Z` for a similar reason, to exclude the newline from the match. You should not be returning error messages from functions, that's what exceptions are for. I changed simple `include?` to `#start_with?` because your `item` might be found elsewhere in the line when we wouldn't want to trigger the change.

```
class FileNotFoundException < RuntimeError; end

def replace_info(item, bar)
  # check if file exists
  raise FileNotFoundException unless File.exist?('site_info.txt')

  # rewrite the file
  File.open('site_info.txt.bak', 'wt') do |w|
    File.open('site_info.txt', 'rt') do |r|
      r.each_line do |line|
        if line.start_with?("[#{item}]")
          line.sub!(/(?<=label2: ).*?\Z/, bar)
        end
        w.write(line)
      end
    end
  end

  # replace the old file
  File.rename('site_info.txt.bak', 'site_info.txt')
end

replace_info("item", "bar")
```

Comment: yes I anticipated my regrex might be off.  More important: I hoped to circumvent the "big problem" with `.sub` Any thoughts to workarounds? -it's sort of drained me today.

Comment: I still haven't quite grasped bang methods quite yet (! results in permanent change ). can you point to concise documentation?

Comment: foo, open a new file for writing before `IO.foreach...`. You might make both filenames arguments of the method. If you want to replace the old file with the new one, do that after, outside this method. Then right before `foreach`'s `end` write `line` to the output file. btw, `foreach` reads an input file, so `IO.foreach(fname) { |...]` is sufficient (no `'a+`').

Comment: @Amadan if I may ask 1) the benefit of `raise subclass` vs `return [string]`? 2.) if I am flipping back and forth between files, must I always swap the text files in the `.rb` source code? I ask because the info for `item` will change occasionally.  In essence this txt file serves as a bare-knuckle database I've created...

Comment: 1) A function should ideally do one thing. If it is changing a file, it should not be worrying about error messages. If it is printing errors to the user, it shouldn't be changing files. Besides, what if a function wants to return a string, but can have an error? 2) What do you mean, flipping back and forth? And if you want a bare-knuckle database, use SQLite3 or a text file with YAML or JSON, no reason to reinvent the wheel. :)